# Object not detaching from the nhibernate session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I've got an MVC application using nHibernate for it's data persistence but for some reason in spite of evicting my object from the session it is still being persisted to the database.

I have a complex object that I let the user apply a change to and have it recalculate child collections based off the new value of a property on the parent object. But I don't want these changes persisted because I'm passing the resulting changes back to the view to render as a preview only. The user can commit them but using a different action.

Immediately after I query nHibernate for my object in this process I evict it from the session but for some reason it's still being persisted.

According to the nHibernate Profiler, it seems to be due to a Transaction Commit I have in a filter decorating my Controller Action. This was done due to a best practice I read concerning items read from the database not being cached to the 2nd level cache unless the transaction is committed, even when no modifications were made. Even so, it doesn't explain why the commit would cause an evicted object to have changes persisted to the database. I am assuming I am missing something that will explain this behaviour but I'm not sure what?

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you are querying an object, then evict it from session and make changes for the user preview?

Are you changing child collections also? Because as far as I remember, when evicting object from NH, it doesn't automatically evict related child objects (at least in NH v2.x).

So when you change some child object (and you haven't explicitly evicted it) it tries to persist it and because of some cascading rules tries to persist parent object also.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder about evict at all actually. The more I search the more references I find saying Evict() simply removes an item from the first level cache. But very little mentions anything about it being detached from the session. I would like to be able to flip a switch and make the object in memory transient instead of persistent.

Comment: I haven't used Evict() myself. Actually I tried to used it, but give up for the reasons I mentioned.
I just do a rollback when I don't want to save entities (eg. when before save validation fails).